# Why du -sh * tells me sys has 0 size?

Tags: files, du

I use `du -sh *` to find out the size of folders, but the `sys` folder is giving me 0, and the same about any folder inside `sys`.
`find . | wc -l` gives me 11k files.
Do you know why and can you suggest a workaround?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

What do you want to work around? 0 is the correct number. `/sys` is a virtual filesystem, consisting of kernel data exposed in a filesystem-like interface. It does not actually take up any space.

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't know about that. No workaround needed :-)